# Convert certain data bind values into Json using Knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

I am new to the knockoutjs, I have following viewmodel:

```
var Testing = function(){

   this.Username = ko.observable("");  
   this.Password = ko.observable("");  
   this.email = ko.observable("");

}
```

I need to convert only certain data bind values(Username and password) into json. All the values are getting converted into json when I use like this `data = ko.toJSON(this);`

So how I can filter certain data bind values and convert into json ?

Comment: Also check out this answer if you want to override the toJSON method [Knockout serialization with ko.toJSON - how to ignore properties that are null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461037/knockout-serialization-with-ko-tojson-how-to-ignore-properties-that-are-null)

Answer (score 2):

You could either only serialize what you want or take Ryan Neidermeyer's approach and just remove the unwanted properties -

```
var items = ko.toJS(this);
var mappedItems = ko.utils.arrayMap(items, function(item) {
    delete item.email;
    return item;
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution.I don't want to delete any of them,i need to select certain values and converted into JSon while sending into server.

Comment: This doesn't actually delete them just creates a json payload and then removes unnecessary properties from that payload only

Comment: I used Your solution in my code but the item is not getting deleted and here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PavithraHM/4FGXB/5/  when i gave alert before mappedarray its getting converted into Javascript object, and the item is not getting loaded.Once i delete the items i need to convert rest of things to json.   where i can find this kind of methods in the knockoutjs Document?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `toJSON` method to your ViewModel and do what ever filtering you need there:

```
ViewModel.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this);
    // remove any unneeded properties
    delete copy.unneedProperty;
    return copy;
}
```

Take a look at the [docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) for more information about serializing to JSON.

Comment: I used Your solution in my code but the item is not getting deleted and here is jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/PavithraHM/4FGXB/6/ ,Once i delete the items i need to convert rest of things to json. where i can find this kind of methods in the knockoutjs Document?