# passing replacer to knockout ko.mapping.toJSON

Tags: knockout.js

It seems `ko.mapping.toJSON` is calling `stringifyJson: function (data, replacer, space)` behind the closed doors, but it doesn't allow the caller to pass the optional params (`replacer` and `space`) so they can be passed along to `stringifyJson`.

Is there another overload or am I missing the whole point?

The actual story:

I am using `ko.mapping.toJSON` to json `stringify` my view model for sending back to server, which it does perfectly as it ignore all other properties that didn't came from store/db.

But I want to tweak it a little to save some `KB`'s by leaving out `null` values.

Comment: Why not use `ko.toJSON`? It allows the extra parameter https://stackoverflow.com/a/12461567/4887159

Answer (score 0):

It seems indeed it does not currently [support passing](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/issues/155) `stringify` optional params and the work around would be:

```
ko.toJSON(ko.mapping.toJS(....), replacer, space)
```